# Scripting engine that's lightweight, cross-platform, functional, and statically typed

Tags: open-source, library, cross-platform, scripting, embeddable

I'm looking for a scripting engine to embed in a C program. Here's what I'm looking for in it:

- FOSS (doesn't matter whether it's a copyleft or pushover license)
- C interop (though I expect every scripting engine to support this, so this doesn't really narrow it down)
- Lightweight (not hundreds of MB)
- Cross-platform (at a minimum, should build on Windows, macOS, and Linux systems and x86-64 and AArch64 architectures without needing to jump through any crazy hoops)
- Good support for a functional programming paradigm
- Strongly and statically typed, ideally with a Haskell/ML-style type system
- Bonus: It would be nice if it were pure like Haskell or PureScript

Lua's type system is basically nonexistent (every non-primitive type is an array/map hybrid called a "table"), so it's out. GHC is a gigantic monstrosity (hundreds of MB), so it's out too.

Comment: Would JavaScript + TypeScript work? I'm just not sure about C interop.

Comment: What about [Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/embedding/index.html)? (Never done it)

Comment: @dwjohnston That seems like it might be an okay language (even though JS sure has its warts...) but which engine fits the bill? Neither SpiderMonkey nor V8 seem exactly lightweight.

Comment: Not strongly typed, but TCL is another contender in the Lua class.

Comment: I think Lua is popular for this sort of thing.

Comment: @EricS Yeah, I mentioned that in the question, but I'm looking for something a bit more type-safe than Lua.

Comment: Julia can have static typing, but it isn’t targeted as an embedded language as far as I know.